# Running Minecraft Windows on virtual machine Mac

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, minecraft

I play Minecraft PE with friends, and I've always wanted to be able to play on my MacBook. However, the only edition available to macOS is Java edition, and very few people I know play this. I would rather not partition my disk to include windows, but would it work to use a virtual machine running Windows to play it? Mostly I just want it to be faster than if I played on my iPad. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you want isn’t possible, cross-play to my knowledge, is only a feature of Minecraft on the Windows Store and not the Java version which runs on MacOS

Comment: @Ramhound that's why I'm considering a virtual machine that is running windows

Comment: Minecraft will run absolutely horrible within a VM

Comment: If using Minecraft PE within Mac is a possible solution to your needs as opposed to using Minecraft Windows..., you can download an Android Emulator like [BlueStacks](https://www.bluestacks.com/) on your mac, you can then install Minecraft PE through this. (PS this solution does work on windows, however I have never used BlueStacks on Mac so I cannot be certain that it will work as not all android apps are compatible)

Comment: If you don't actually mean "Minecraft PE" then you should edit your question, because it currently, is only asking about "Minecraft PE".  Regardless my personally experiences won't change with regards to Minecraft performance within a VM.

Comment: @CraftyB Thanks for the suggestion I'll look into it

Answer (score -1):

There Are lots of vm programs for macOS I use virtualbox (look it up)
But you will need at least 1 gig of ram for the VM and you will need at lest 25 gigs of your disk space for a virtual hard disk.

But 30 gigs for Disk space is recommend and 2 gigs of RAM

Comment: "25 gigs for a virtual hard disk". 25 gigs ram or disk space?

Comment: 25 gigs of Disk space 1 gig of ram min

Comment: I have 480 gigs of disk and 8 gigs of ram

Comment: Ok, I would make a VM With 30 Gigs for Disk Space and 2 Gigs for Ram